How to use Named Credential + External Credential for Marketing Cloud Transactional Messaging API
I am trying to use Named Credential for Marketing Cloud Transactional Messaging API. And I am having issues sending SMS.
I was able to setup an External Credential:
Authentication Protocol = OAuth 2.0
Authentication Flow Type = Client Credentials with Client Secret Flow
And I was able to authenticate using the Client Id and Client Secret.
Please see below:
NAMED_CREDENTIAL_REQUEST NamedCallout[Named Credential Id=xxxx, Named Credential Name=MCCredential, Endpoint=https://mcls-xxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/sms/messages/xxx-xxx, Method=POST, External Credential Type=EXTERNAL, HTTP Header Authorization=Method: Bearer - Credential: xxx, Content-Type=application/json;charset=UTF-8, Request Size bytes=296, Retry on 401=True]
However, I could not send an SMS.
See that status is 404:
02:08:27:165 NAMED_CREDENTIAL_RESPONSE NamedCallout[Named Credential Id=xxx, Named Credential Name=MCCredential, Status Code=404, Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, Response Size bytes=134, Overall Callout Time ms=1137, Connect Time ms=1
I believe the access token received is not enough because I needed(not required) the account_id for the request as per documentation. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/access-token-s2s.html#access-token-return
Using Custom Setting to set the credentials with account_id is working fine.
callout request for accesstoken -> callout send sms using the accesstoken
I also tried removing the account_id with this approach and I got the same error. So I'm quite sure that this issue is caused by the missing account_id on the credential.
Is there a way to pass the account_id or somewhat override the authentication in the external credential? I want to use the named credential to avoid 2 callouts and to completely remove the custom setting.
Note: I don't have the visibility on the MC side and have no experience on MC. I probably need to reach out to them.

When the client (MC calls it package) is created on MC side, it's done so in the context of  the MC tenant and its underlying business units (organization/structure). Needing or not needing the account id is based on that. Talk to your MC admin. If the account id is needed, unfortunately you won't be able to use Named/Ext Cred to do oAuth because with account id the flow is not oAuth standard. (You can still use NC/EC to store credentials and use them in your Apex code)

I see, thanks! @identigral
